# Android Library + JUnit Testing in IntelliJ

Tags: android, testing, intellij-idea, junit, frameworks

I want to start developing an Android library and use JUnit Testing.
How can I create the project in IntelliJ for this?

I tried creating an Android library module and an Android testing module, but it won't work.

Comment: I prefer using sbt with this plugin - https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin .  You can import sbt projects into intellJ idea.  You can add tests to your Android project, which works just fine.  Also have a look at http://robolectric.org/

Comment: I know Robolectric. Its pretty fun to work with.

Comment: But I want to work with IntelliJ + Gradle as Build System. :/

Comment: I am afraid I don't know much about gradle.  However, I don't believe IntelliJ wouldn't be able to work with it, so simply create a basic gradle android application and then try importing it into Idea.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work. :( But I found a very cool, testing-ready, template.
https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle